# Teams Bot Authentication - not redirecting

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I have been using below examples. Had deployed the bot on teams with app studio, where it worked fine. When App Studio came to end-of-life and we converted the bot manifest in developers portal it doesn't seems to be authorizing (redirecting). On web teams app it gives an error as

[On teams app web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtwKC.png)

and when I try to access on android phone teams app,  it tries to redirect but errors out as below.

[Android teams app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0KmF.jpg)

Can someone please help.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-botframework

Comment: Check the application insight as well.

Comment: Could you please share console logs if there are any? Can you once try using the manifest provided in the sample - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/TeamsAppManifest

Comment: I tried the only difference was of validDomains  which I changed. but nothing.

Comment: Could you please share console logs?